# how to enforce static folder paths after deflate within ADFv2

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ZIP file which lives at a [generic URL](https://www.sos.wa.gov/_assets/corps/jsonCorpsData.zip) that contains four large JSON files.

In a perfect world, within a single pipeline, I would want each of these files to be extracted, parsed and loaded into their respective Azure tables.

I can see where I can use deflate instructions at many points within datasets and activities but each time I use one to deflate the ZIP, ADF wants to extract the output into a folder named with a GUID that I can't seem to find the source of.  Could someone please help me get toward my goal of unzipping the files and loading to tables?  This seems like a simple task and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Hi Tim, the unzip in ADF Copy activity should put the files into a folder names as the source zip file. For you case, could you share the activity RunID for our further investigation?

Comment: Sure, I just finished another example where it happened again: PipelineID: 9ed4e519-a624-4dae-8e62-1f967c3f74f7 Activity RunID:e8bd7416-117b-4925-88d1-bd25ce6cacf5 ZIP file folder name: ba1fcb85-e405-41f8-aba7-9ab7be957206

Comment: Hi Tim, I think it is caused by a limitation in ADF's http connector. Could you try specify the fileName jsonCorpsData.zip as relativeUrl in data set, and set the base url "https://www.sos.wa.gov/_assets/corps/" as url in linked service? Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#linked-service-properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to figure this out by breaking the steps into further detail within the pipeline instead of having it all managed within one.  Felt cumbersome but it worked so...whatever!